# Slow query inner join many tables HSQLDB

Tags: performance, hsqldb

I use hsqldb for my embedded DB in my java web application i must use this query for giving data from HSQLDB, is there any way to better performance of this query ?

```
SELECT  RU.c AS Title, RU.g AS FullCode, RU.id AS RUAccountID,RU.i AS Published, RU.b AS RUAccountCode, 
    PC.id AS PCID,SL.id AS SLAccountID, SL.a AS gl_id,GL.a AS at_id
           from GLBL_PC AS PC
             INNER JOIN  FINC_RU AS RU ON RU.F = PC.ID
             INNER JOIN  FINC_SL AS SL ON SL.ID = RU.A
             INNER JOIN  FINC_GL AS GL ON GL.ID = SL.A
           WHERE RU.e=1 AND RU.a=6
           ORDER BY  RU.b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the GBL-PC and FINC_RU tables in the list.

If the FINC_RU table is large, you can then create an index on FINC_RU(A, E) to speed things up.

Each ID column should have a PRIMARY KEY constraint or an index.